# My website is not working in android uc browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, uc-browser

this is my website http://vegidelivery.com/silver-mart/ products are not loading, and '+' button in side menu is not working , it working fine in other android browsers like chrome and Firefox, i am not able to understand , what is happening in uc browser.

Answer (score 1):

Android UC has 2 variants.

- UC Browser
- UC Mini

UC Mini is meant for performance and speed on page loading. So UC Mini didnot support JavaScript in a wide range.
If your problem is with UC Browser, then try to debug it by throwing an alert function to check whether JS is supported or not.